# I need help to show that $E(\sum x)=\sum E(x)$

Tags: self-study, distributions, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, variance

If for a normal distribution $E(x)=\overline{x}$ and if we have $E(\overline{x})=E(\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i)=\frac1N\sum_{j=1}^N\left(\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i\right)_j$ how can then $E(\overline{x})=\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^NE(x_i)$ ?

Comment: Expectation is a linear operator, so its (order) can be interchanged with summation and with the constant 1/N. How on earth do you get $E(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^N\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i\right)_j$?

Comment: Well if $E(x)=\overline{x}=\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i$ then $E(\overline{x})=\frac1N\sum_{j=1}^N\left(\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i\right)_j$

Comment: The substitution of "$\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i\right)_{*}$" for "$x_{*}$" is simply nonsensical.

Comment: To "show" something, you have to start somewhere.  What is your definition of expectation and what properties are you willing to assume about it in making your demonstration?  (To limit further downvoting, I will put this question on hold pending your clarifying edits.)

Comment: I started studying statistics only a couple od days ago, and I know that $E(x)=E(\overline{x})=\mu$ for a normally distributed x and large enough number of trials and I have proved it before. Due to my lack of knowledge, inexperience and due to the fact that I assumed all expectations equal arithmetic means (because of being aware of the above mentioned fact), I made such non-sensical questions and statements. Sorry, for spam.

Answer (score 1):

$E(\overline{x})=E(\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i)=\frac1N E\left(\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i\right)=\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^NE(x_i)$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties

Comment: You still just enter the sum with $E$ in the last step, but I need to prove that you can do that. Also the wikipedia page doesn't provide any proof.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147834/proving-the-linearity-property-of-expectation-in-general-set-up. also look at theorem 2.2: http://www.cse.iitd.ac.in/~mohanty/col106/Resources/linearity_expectation.pdf . I don't know if it's what you're looking for, but a simple search on google would've done the trick.

Comment: I understand the proof provided, but is it possible to prove that fact by substituting for every $E(x)=\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i$ and not using $E$ as an operator?. The argument of that substitution would be that for a normal distribution $E(x)=\overline{x}=\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N$.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is not possible to say that $E(\overline{x})=\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N\overline{x}$ since we do not know that the values of the sequence of arithmetic means we obtain by iteratively calculating it for every $x_{N+1}$ are normally distributed around $\mu$ as $N\to\infty$, and $E(x)=\overline{x}$ only for enough large $N$ and normally distributed data. That's why I think to prove the original statement by substituting $\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N\overline{x}_i$ for every $E(x)$ is impossible.